# GUI Development - Free Tools

Tags: swing, user-interface, architecture

We are looking at building a GUI application having the following attributes -
   * approx 100 screens
   * approx 200 users
   * interfaces with 8 different legacy applications (protocols tbd but we are assuming web services will be exposed)
   * has a separate data store for storing authentication and authorisation info along with few other information.

We are trying to avoid spending any money on procurement of physical servers, application servers etc.So we thought instead of building a web application , we could develop a standalone GUI based application that could be deployed on users' desktops considering that the users are less and the access to this application is confined to our organisation.

We were thinking of Java Swing as one of the options to consider. Is it a good choice? Please advice on the other options that we need to think about. We thought MS products would involving licensing costs to buy the product hence we are looking at developing the application using some free software tools.

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
V

Comment: I doubt this question will last long -- doesn't really fit the SO guidelines.  Why does it have to be a standalone app?  Pretty much any open source solution is viable for developing a web app.  They all have frameworks.  On your short list for consideration I would recommend java, php, ruby and python.

Comment: Thanks gview. In case of web application, we would have to procure at least 2 servers. So the cost of procuring the physical servers and cost of OS licensing / support and cost of application servers / support made us move towards standalone app - since no one outside our organisation is going to access it and user base is quite less.Our organisation doesn't want to spend any money on this application.

Comment: Vicky, how does making a web app require multiple servers?

Comment: Sorry, if I have not explained it properly.I thought a web application has to be deployed on a application server (e.g. JBoss) , which has to be deployed on a physical server.We might require couple of servers for load balancing / fault tolerance etc. For some of our existing web applications we have 4 physical servers - apache web servers are installed in 2 servers to which the request comes from hardware load balancer and we have got 2 physical servers where application server is installed. The request to these servers comes from apache web servers.

Comment: You can run your entire stack on a single machine.  You only need an app server if you plan to develop in java, and even java allows the creation of servlets, so an app server is not strictly required.  The other languages I suggested are all FOSS and can be run fastcgi or often as apache modules. Even java app servers have options like glassfish and jboss.  If you don't use at least one server, I don't see how you plan to handle the authentication/user system.

Comment: I thought we might need at least 2 in case one of the server crashes. I think there would be a cost associated with producing the application server , support / licence cost associated with the OS that has to be installed on the server. We are having jboss server for one of our customers for which we are paying annual support fee, hence I thought jboss / glass fish would also add up to the cost. With respect to authentication , we already have a database that has the user credentials.

Comment: We thought of making the standalone app fetch info from the db (we have got a enterprise middleware , so one option is to expose a web service using the middleware which can be consumed by standalone app). Thank you very much for your prompt responses and your valuable time.

Comment: The jboss model is to give the software for free and charge for service.  You don't need to pay for that if you plan to support yourself.  Ditto glassfish afaik. Many people are using Linux as the operating system which is also free.

Comment: Thanks gview. I am with you - but unfortunately our org isn't prepared to spend on servers due to budget constraints :( That's the reason why we are planning to do it as a standalone app. Is standalone app outdated and not the way to go anymore?

Comment: @gview : a server to host a webapp used by 200 users would cost what? 1000 dollars? And developing, maintaining, deploying your app with 200 screens and the web services will cost what? let's say 5 days per screen * 200 screens * 500 dollars per day = 500,000 dollars. So the physical server cost is approximately 0.2% of the total cost. At least a webapp will avoid you to support 200 different installs at each version of the product, and you'll be sure everyone uses the last version.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I'm assuming you meant that for Vicky ;D

Comment: Does your company employee dedicated developers or are they trying to get non-developers to 'figure it out'? Every time I've seen this done it's ended in disaster. You might want to bite the bullet and outsource this project. An experienced consultant at ~100$/hour will be more cost effective than a non-developer at ~30$/hour IMO. Apologies in advance if this is not the case at your company.

Comment: Guys, Thank you very much for your advice.We have decided web application is the way to go. Your inputs helped a great deal.gview,JB,Vicky,Kingo - Thanks. Hi Jordan - no , we are company of developers. My team has experience only in developing web apps , one of our guys suggested standalone app might suit the purpose as company doesn't  want to spend anything.So I was trying get some expert opinions here. Grateful to people who have spent their valuable time on my question.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Swing and have written many applications with it, but I'm not sure the argument that you will get a cheaper solution because you have to procure less physical servers is a good reason for it.

There are other ways to use computational capacity on the client side. For example you could use [SmartGWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/). With a browser based solution you get easy deployment and have no problems with client-server communications (i.e. no proxy hell). It's possible to get all of this solved with a standalone GUI, but it requires experience and time (== money).

I think a standalone GUI is a good idea if you need a "rich" user experience and tight integration with the native environment. Web apps are generally less snappy and not so well integrated. If it's just about editing data on a server, the standalone GUI does not really have any advantages.

Answer (score -2):

I won't rehash what we talked about in the comments.   It seems you are focused on java gui solutions. With that said there are alternatives for developing gui applications with free tools.  Just to name a couple, you could develop your client with Adobe Flex or Adobe Air, use python, php or ruby and GTK, or develop a windows GUI app using c# if your target os is windows.  Similar to Air, Microsoft Silverlight is an option.  Java is not the only solution.
Many Java gui apps are written using swing.  The major competitor to Swing has long been SWT which is used for eclipse and by IBM.  Javafx is a newer/alternative platform Sun/Oracle is behind, you should also look at.  To be complete, you should also take a look at qt jambi that lets you develop in java against the Qt framework.

Comment: How is Swing a discontinued project. It's part of Java SE, and is live and well. Very far from being discontinued or abandoned.

Comment: @JB Nizet: ok I guess I'm out of touch with the Swing situation. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It would have been really easy to check if this bold claim could be true. Just look at the swing tag in stackoverflow, it has more than 8000 questions. SWT, for example only has 1000 and Adobe AIR and GTK have less than 2000. Javafx 2.0 and all its capabilities can now be used from Swing, so Swing has gotten a tremendous boost recently.

Comment: @kingo: There was nothing bold about the statement, it was quite true at one time, here's one of numerous references:  http://www.jroller.com/agoubard/entry/the%5Fswing%5Fapplication%5Fframework%5Fstill  This is way off topic. Even though I was not clear on the status of swing, I stated it was a viable option.  I enumerated the alternatives as I see them.

Comment: @gview: "it was quite true at one time" - no that was never true. There are always people who are unhappy about the state of affairs , but Swing was never in any way "a discontinued project". I'm sorry we have to discuss this, but it's on topic.

Comment: It's not relevant, when I stated it was a viable option.  I guess I confused Swing itself with JSR 296.  Either way it doesn't change anything about the core of my answer which is ... there are many FOSS Gui application development choices.